# How to sort the values of a dictionary in descending order and the keys alphabetically

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

How do we sort values in a dictionary in descending order, and if there are two similar values, sort the key of those values alphabetically?

Like the following example :

```
Input = {'robert':13, 'walter':17, 'andrew':16, 'adrian':16, 'simon':15, 'santiago':15}
```

```
Output = {'walter':17, 'adrian':16, 'andrew':16, 'santiago':15, 'simon':15}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can **sort** values of dictionary in this way:

```
output = dict(sorted(inp.items(), key=lambda item: item[1], reverse=True))
```

**output:**

> {'walter': 17, 'andrew': 16, 'adrian': 16, 'simon': 15, 'santiago':
> 15, 'robert': 13}